# Can the perspective camera show distant objects larger than closer ones?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have a simple scene in ThreeJS that shows two equal sized rectangular shapes, with the same dimensions but separated on the Z-axis. The camera is positioned directly above the shapes looking down on them at an angle.

Without any tweaks, this looks like the following image. Note the 'smaller' rectangle is further from the camera, so it appears smaller:

[image]

Is it possible to set it up so that the more distant object *appears* larger, rather than the closer object occluding the distant one (since they are exactly the same size), like the following image:

[image]

In the image above, the relative size of the lower rectangle is tweaked, but I'd rather keep the models accurate and only change the camera view, since manipulating the objects (and placing other objects in the same space) with the correct relative sizes will be easier.

*Note*: To be clear, these are rectangles viewed at an angle from the camera. This means I'm looking for realistic perspective in one direction and an inverted perspective in another direction.

Comment: This really isn't how perspective works. Can you post some images or a fiddle?

Comment: Then that's not [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection). I'd start with [Reverse Perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_perspective), though some quick searching didn't come up with much on how to implement it. The idea being that rather than projecting _toward_ the camera onto a viewport between the objects and the camera, you project _from_ the camera to a viewport _behind_ the objects. Good luck!

Comment: I likely misunderstand. Wouldn't the result of such a transformation look identical to an orthograhic camera?

Comment: I've updated with more images - @TheJim01 - you are on the right track, but I was hoping for a slightly different result, although the same solution might work. But if I need to implement a new camera to do it, its out of scope for this project.

Comment: I see, so you're looking to apply perspective deformation with orthographic scaling. I know you're not looking to change your objects, but it might be easier to do so. You'd stick with an orthographic camera (and projection matrix), but create per-frame per-object transformations to scale/skew your objects in the scene to give the _appearance_ of perspective deformation. I'm sure it's harder to do than my words imply, and it's unfortunately beyond my current skill set. I'll be interested to follow your progress...

Comment: Your looking to 'skew' your projection matrix. In the real world this effect is ahieved with a "tilt shift" lens

Comment: @TheJim01 i think you can do what you're describing by just changing the depthrest and rendering the backside of the geometries.

Answer (score -1):

Is something like [this](https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/EwmLgj) what you're looking for?

The second cube (red) is 20 units behind the first one (green), but they appear the same size (they **are** the same size, using the same geometry).

It was done using an [`OrthographicCamera`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/OrthographicCamera), which removes the perspective and shows everything as being on the same plane.

You will need to set the bounds of the camera. I did it like so:

```
var width = window.innerWidth / 50;
var height = window.innerHeight / 50;

var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    width / -2, width / 2, height / 2, height / -2, 1, 100
);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what the title of the question says. But in the body he says *is it possible to set it up so that the more distant object appears **larger**, rather than the closer object occluding the distant one (since **they are exactly the same size**).* That sounds like he wants them to look like they're the same size.

Comment: I appreciate the answer - I'm not beholden to a perspective camera, but I don't think an OrthographicCamera will do what I need, since I actually want accurate perspective in one dimension and a reverse / inverse perspective in another dimension.